# Differential Privacy error in PyTorch using Opacus PrivacyEngine - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, federated-learning

The problem of the given code is:

```
line 25, in <module> privacy_engine = PrivacyEngine(model, batch_size=64, 
sample_size=60000, alphas=range(2,32), noise_multiplier=1.3, max_grad_norm=1.0)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch_size'
```

[An image of the code is attached in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaqD5.png) .

The code is given below:

```py
# Step 1: Importing PyTorch and Opacus
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import numpy as np
from opacus import PrivacyEngine
from tqdm import tqdm

# Step 2: Loading MNIST Data
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets.MNIST('../mnist', train=True, download=True,
               transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), 
               (0.3081,)),]),), batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_workers=1, pin_memory=True)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets.MNIST('../mnist', train=False, 
              transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), 
              (0.3081,)),]),), batch_size=1024, shuffle=True, num_workers=1, pin_memory=True)

# Step 3: Creating a PyTorch Neural Network Classification Model and Optimizer
model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 8, 2, padding=3), torch.nn.ReLU(), torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2, 1),
        torch.nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 4, 2),  torch.nn.ReLU(), torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2, 1), torch.nn.Flatten(), 
        torch.nn.Linear(32 * 4 * 4, 32), torch.nn.ReLU(), torch.nn.Linear(32, 10))

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.05)

# Step 4: Attaching a Differential Privacy Engine to the Optimizer
privacy_engine = PrivacyEngine(model, batch_size=64, sample_size=60000, alphas=range(2,32), 
                                noise_multiplier=1.3, max_grad_norm=1.0)
```

How do I fix this issue in the PrivacyEngine of Opacus for differential privacy?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify 'batch_size=64' to '64' or put an in a variable outside of function instantiation. you have to do that for all the inputs btw.